# how to revert GitHub repository to previous commit?

Tags: repository

it is related to GitHUB.

I AM UNABLE TO MAKE CHANGES AND REVERT IN GITHUB
I want to undo a whole commit with all the changes. Instead of doing all this manually , I want to know more about  how to revert a commit